# SSRS Conversion from String "MonthName" to Date is not valid

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am fairly new to SSRS. I am trying to get MonthName from a text parameter based on which I want to set another parameter called FromDate which will be the first date of the selected month. But when I am using below expression its giving a conversion error. Below is the expression that I am using to find the first date of the selected month.

```
=DateSerial(Year(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), Month(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Can somebody provide any suggestion on how to do this? Also is it possible to do this for last date of the month too?

Comment: Soemthing along the lines of `DateSerial(Year(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), Month(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), "1")`

Comment: Can you please give an example of what the parameter value will look like?

Comment: @Lucky ParameterName.Value will be first three letters of the selected month like May,Jun,Jul etc.

Comment: @Programmermid OK, when you right click your parameter and go to properties, then Available Values, can you tell me what the value and label is for January? Is this manually entered or coming from a dataset?